# jquery get number from id

Tags: jquery, get, numbers

how can i get the number from a div tag's id?

example:

```
<div id="button1"></div>
```

how can i get the 1 and store it in a variable?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
var id = $("div").attr('id').replace(/button/, '');
```

Comment: great! thats what totally i need! thanks so big thanks to you pal

Answer (score 13):

Your "id" values cannot be purely numeric; they need to start with a letter or "_" like an identifier. (**Note**: that's not true in HTML5 documents.) Once you've got a number in your "id" value like that, you would just use the jQuery `attr()` function to get the id:

```
 var theId = parseInt($('div.whatever').attr('id').replace(/[^\d]/g, ''), 10);
```

Comment: may I ask u a question. what does /[^\d]/g mean?

Comment: It's a regular expression. It matches any non-digit with this part: 
"[^\d]".  The "g" at the end tells Javascript to repeat the "replace" operation for all non-digits it finds in the string.

Comment: This is the best answer. I had no idea I could use parseInt with words and numbers. It filters out all the text and just returns the number. So cool, and so easy

Answer (score 3):

```
// replace all non-digits with nothing
alert($('div').attr("id").replace(/\D/g,''));
```

If you like, you can just grab the numbers at the end:

```
// <div id="_34_foo_555"></div>
alert($('div').attr("id").match(/\d+$/));
// alerts "555"
```

Answer (score 1):

If `button` is a constant prefix, you can do this:

```
var number = parseInt(element.id.match(/^button(\d+)$/)[1], 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get in the habit of using delimiters in your attribute names (ie, button-1, button_1). One of the advantages, of many, is  that it makes it easier to extract a number, or some other information, from the field (ie, by splitting the string at '-').

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I'd like to add the idea of using a `data-` attribute rather than encoding information in an id:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var element = document.getElementById('button1');
  var number = parseInt(element.getAttribute('data-index'), 10);
  console.log(number);
}
```

```html
<button id="button1" data-index="1"></button>
```

This way you don't need to go through all of the matching and whatnot.