# Jquery: Getting the number from ID

Tags: jquery

You mentioned this in another question: [jquery get number from id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427853/jquery-get-number-from-id)

You should get in the habit of using delimiters in your attribute names (ie, button-1, button_1). One of the advantages, of many, is that it makes it easier to extract a number, or some other information, from the field (ie, by splitting the string at '-').

How would you extract the number if you are using a delimiter in your attribute names?

Thanks!

Comment: The [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2427872/678801) in the question you refer to answer exactly that, right?

Answer (score 5):

1. `.attr('id')` can be used to retrieve the ID attribute.
2. Then, use the `.split` function to split the string by a separator.
3. Get the number from index `[1]`.

Code:

```
 var delimiter = '-';
 var num = $("element").attr('id').split(delimiter)[1];
 // Expected format: <anything 1>-<anything 2>
 // Note that <anything 2> is not necessarily a number
```

The previous method is very dependent on the id format. A more solid method is a regexp:

```
var num = /\d+/.exec($("element").attr('id')); // Selects all consecutive digits
// Examples:
//  button_1 = 1    button2 = 2     1st = 1     button4--5 = 4
```

To match the digits at the end, use:

```
var num = /\d+(?=\D*$)/.exec($("element").attr('id'));
```

Comment: Could you explain `(?=\D*$)`? Why not just `/\d+$/`?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas `\D*` matches any possible non-digit characters. `(?=\D*$)` is a look-ahead: It matches only if the contained match is found. `/\d+(?=\D*$)/` is more tolerant than `/\d+$/`: My suggested RegExp also returns a digit for `"button_112_id"`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `selector` and `delimiter` with your actual values.

```
var parts = $('#selector').attr('id').split('delimiter');
var my_number = parts[parts.length - 1];
alert(my_number);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have already suggested you can split on the hypen or underscore very simply, using:

```
var number = str.split("-")[1]
```

[jQuery split() documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Another viable option here is to just extract the numbers using regex patterns. This is helpful if the string you're extracting numbers from has no delimeter. I don't use delimeters in my particular style of coding, so this what I use:

```
var number = str.match(/\d+/);
```

[jQuery match() documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)