# Jquery filter class and set as a variable

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the class of a clicked element eg.  '.thumbs1' and set it as a variable but remove everything but the number '1'.

I have found a way to remove everything but the number using the following code but i do not know the syntax to store it as a variable.

```
$(this).attr('class').replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
```

I want to do something like:

```
var i = $(this).attr('id').replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
```

This is obviously wrong but you get the idea. Ta

Comment: Why is `var i = $(this).attr('id').replace(/[^\d]/g, '');` wrong? it looks fine to me! (except that you wrote there `id` instead of `class`...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a `data` attribute instead? This is the kind of thing they were designed for:

```
<a href="#" data-id="1" class="thumbs">#1</a>
<a href="#" data-id="2" class="thumbs">#2</a>
```

```
$(".thumbs").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id"); // = 1 or 2 in this case
});
```

Attempting to parse `id` attributes or `class` names to get at a value stored in them is very counter productive, as you're now discovering.

Answer (score 0):

No that is correct you try

```
var id = $("div").attr('id').replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
```

or check this [Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427853/jquery-get-number-from-id)