# javascript get number from id

Tags: javascript

how can I get the number from a div tag's id using JavaScript?

```
<body id="page1">...</body>
```

how can i get the 1 and store it in a variable?
(A similar question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427853/jquery-get-number-from-id) using jQuery.)

Comment: Do you not consider `jQuery` javascript?

Comment: @Aiman Al-Eryani. Due to speed considerations, I prefer to use js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it using **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)**

```js
alert(
  document.body.id.match(/\d+/)[0]
);
```

```html
<body id="page1">...</body>
```

Comment: Thank you @Pranav C Balan. What is the diiference of your answer and steppefox answer which uses '$' sign?

Comment: @ObjectOrientedMan : `$` uses to match at the end of string.... my initial answer contains `$`.....